Is "language" countable or uncountable here?
I saw this essay question on a website (not a credible site). I think language is countable here because it's about foreign languages. But the question uses it uncountably. So, should language or languages be used?

Since not all children have a natural talent for language, not all of
them should start learning a foreign language in primary school. Do
you agree or disagree?


It's most definitely NOT about foreign languages! The whole point of the TRUISM that "children have a natural talent for language", and Chomsky's ideas about "universal grammar" are predicated on the fact that every child easily learns its own native language. And since children are "evolved" to easily learn their mother tongue, it's not surprising they can "transfer" that skill to learning other languages. The idea that some children don't have a natural talent for language sounds spurious to me.

@FumbleFingers - Some children do have language disorders that make them slow to learn to talk.

Thank you both for your comments. I think what the question really wants to ask is: Since not all children have a natural talent for foreign languages, not all of them should start learning one in primary school. Do you agree or disagree?
What do you think?

@KateBunting: Yeah - like some children are true hermaphrodites! For all practical purposes, they're not significant, and it's misleading to suggest the (possible) presence of such "rare, pathological" cases should be a consideration in the context of teaching foreign languages in primary schools.

Newbie - FumbleFingers and I obviously disagree about this (see my answer).

Note, while "language" is fine here, "languages" could also be ok, as a condensation of "learning secondary languages" (though it would possibly alter the meaning)

@FumbleFingers Although the original author's intent isn't clear to me without context (and I suspect wouldn't be even with!), as long as we're talking educational philosophies, I took it to be more like Gardner's notions of multiple intelligences, that some people are more disposed to talent at math, or science, or for that matter sports, than wordsmithing. It's possible that the author is posing a straw-man "modest suggestion" that such kids shouldn't get secondary language training.

@AndyBonner: You can think what you like. I think whoever wrote the cited text is an ignoramus who has no idea about how human brains and language work. Being able to acquire and use true symbolic language is just about the only characteristic "all" humans share, but no animals have (I don't accept any supposed examples of animals using arbitrary symbols with associated grammar; any such are just "tricks").

Even though foreign languages are mentioned in the second half of the sentence, language in the singular could be understood as meaning 'the skill of expressing oneself in words'. If a child can't yet use their mother tongue effectively, there is no point in trying to teach them another language.
